# How to transfer large file over HTTP

Tags: wcf, soap

I am looking for best practice / guidance for upgrading our legacy infrastructure to sustain future growth. Below is the summary of my current architecture and issue.

We have legacy HTTP SOAP web service to upload data files from clients to the central server. These files in turn get pulled by data custodians. In past we only had about 30 clients uploading about 10-20MB/client every week to central server and only one custodian which pulled data every night. (e.g. ~80MB/day upload & ~80MB/day download). This was run by 1 IIS and it was sufficient.

Currently we have about 350 clients some sending about 300MB/week, our daily traffic is about 60GB. This is managed by 3 x IIS behind load balancer and dedicated SQL server. This infrastructure sometimes struggles as we are seeing lot of time outs and failed file transfers.
We are looking into replacing existing file transfer mechanism with something which can sustain future growth as we may be looking to ~1000 clients in a year or so.

File size is between 100KB and 5MB, these needs to be transferred over HTTP/HTTPS (comms are encrypted internally so HTTP/HTTPS does not matter much).

Can anyone please guide me in the direction of what architecture / technology we should be using to make this scalable and efficient? I was looking into replacing SOAP service with WCF web service.

**PS: I cannot use anything but HTTP/HTTPS comms (FTP/P2P/BITS NOT to be used)**

I am happy to provide more information if needed – I just did not know where to start from.

Regards,

Om

Comment: WCF **is** (predominantly) SOAP, just a newer framework with .NET.  For large files, look into streaming with WCF.

Comment: Hi Tim, Sorry for the delayed response but thank you very much for your guidance, I will have a look.